# How to get image from url using c# / javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, httpwebrequest, filepicker.io

I am using file picker apis , i can easily upload my files to there server and they give me a unique url in return . When it comes to again fetch that file its creating a problem to me .

You can tell me how to get back file using that url by using filepicker api .
You can tell me how to use that url and get image , by using c#

When i upload a picture to filepicker.io they return me a json object like following

```
[{"url":"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/kIrtNvQRta7GxlFVfiP2","filename":"brazil.jpg","mimetype":"image/jpeg","size":2660,"key":"ZML3OjrFTVyV4waBzRIT_brazil.jpg","isWriteable":true}]
```

So how to get back that image  file using c# / Filepicket javascript api

**Edit**
In my site user will come and upload many photos , and every link to that photo will be stored in database . Now if user want to see his uploaded pictures then i want to fetch them again from server by `url` . So give your solutions acc. to this scenario .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the picture in a PictureBox first using: `PictureBox.Load(string);`
After the PictureBox is filled with the image from the url, you can decide what to do next like: saving etc.

[PictureBox.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6ak7was.aspx)